# Initializing a multidimensional array, and then printing contents in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

    int weiners[3][2] = {
                       {5, 10, 8},
                       {8, 4, 7},
                       {3, 1, 2},
                       {0, 7, 9}
                     };
    int x,y;

    printf("Weiners:\n_______\n");

    for(x=0;x<=3;++x){
        for(y=0;y<=2;++y){
        printf("%i, ", weiners[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This is just intended to simply create a small multidimensional array, and then use a loop to print the contents. It formats it properly, and the first three columns are correct, the numbers following those are very incorrect. I'm not really sure what's wrong here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSX2M.png

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a `int[3][2]` and you initialize it with 4 x 3 items thus the last items are undefined once the loop reach after the 6th value.

gcc complains about it :

```
array.c: In function `main':
array.c:7: warning: excess elements in array initializer
array.c:7: warning: (near initialization for `weiners[0]')
array.c:8: warning: excess elements in array initializer
array.c:8: warning: (near initialization for `weiners[1]')
array.c:9: warning: excess elements in array initializer
array.c:9: warning: (near initialization for `weiners[2]')
array.c:10: warning: excess elements in array initializer
array.c:10: warning: (near initialization for `weiners[3]')
array.c:10: warning: excess elements in array initializer
array.c:10: warning: (near initialization for `weiners')
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your array is not correct (it's 4x3 instead of 3x2):

```
int weiners[4][3] = {
                   {5, 10, 8},
                   {8, 4, 7},
                   {3, 1, 2},
                   {0, 7, 9}
                 };
```

Alternatively, you could use an array that is actually 3x2 (instead of 4x3), then fix your for loop to use indexing that matches:

```
for(x=0;x<3;++x) {
    for(y=0;y<2;++y) {
```

Comment: @JonMartin Well, it's more that the two don't match...  I'm not sure which is "right"

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just started working with md arrays in C, and I see what I did wrong. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your array needs to be [4][3].

Comment: Good answer. But _slow_ by 90 seconds!

Answer (score 0):

you have given wrong number of rows and columns the format to give it is :-

```
int array[rows][colums]
```

here row=4 and columns=3;

change the loop accordingly.